# Fortran intrinsic keyword in module use statement

Tags: fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, fortran2003

What does it mean when the `intrinsic` keyword is added to the `use` statement for a module, as in the following example?

```
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
```

(From
[7.1 Overview of Fortran interface, FFTW 3.3.6-pl1](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Overview-of-Fortran-interface.html#Overview-of-Fortran-interface))

Does it specify that a module of that name provided with the compiler should be used, even if there is another module of the same name written by the user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `use, intrinsic :: ...` the intrinsic module is indeed chosen.

There is perhaps a slight subtlety in the question worth addressing.  With regards to "a module of that name provided with the compiler should be used", this "should" doesn't indicate a preference but a strong requirement.  That is, if there's no such intrinsic module then compilation cannot succeed.  This shouldn't be a problem with `iso_c_binding` but compilers often offer their own non-standard intrinsic modules.

There is no way to say "use the intrinsic module if it's available, but the user-provided one if not".